# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $a,b \in X$ and let $r,s>0$. Assume that $a \neq b$. Prove that if $r+d(a,b)≤s$, then $B(a;r) \subseteq B(b;s)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $a,b \in X$ and let $r,s>0$. Assume that $a \neq b$. Prove that if $r+d(a,b)≤s$, then $B(a;r) \subseteq B(b;s)$ (where $B(a;r)$ is the open ball centered at a with radius $r$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I'd recommend doing a little more thinking about this. It can be proved directly from definitions. The one trick you need is one you have seen a bunch of times in real analysis

Comment: I got as far as using the triangle inequality to get d(a,b) < d(a,x) + d(b,x) which are both less than r and s respectively, so d(a,b) < r+s but I'm not sure how I can go from there, I think I'm close though?

Comment: You need to prove something about $d(b,x)$, not $d(a,b)$

Answer (score 0):

You need to take an element (say $x$) in $B(a;r)$ and show that $x \in B(b;s)$ i.e $d(x,b)<s$. Therefore, you have to use the triangle inequality in $d(x,b)$, not in $d(a,x)$. Now use the assumptions to conclude.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that should not be asked.